# Formatting checkboxes in django

Tags: css, django, checkbox

i'm trying to add some checkboxes into my form and to make them look nice. The thing is that when I use `{{form.checkBoxFilter}}` the output is like:
[image: Checkboxes]

I would like to have them inline and readable, unfortunately using crispy forms renders them too close to each other.

I found that looping through elements will place them inline but still they're close to each other (their labels are much longer than shown below).

```
{% for x in filter.weights%} {{x}} {%endfor%}
```

[image]

Where to put my css in this case?

filters.py:

```
    weights = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
        label = "Filter by weight",
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=OZ,
        method = 'filter_by_checkbox'
    )
```

Adding directly into static/css won't work :

```
   input[type=checkbox]
  {
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 20px 15px 0px 3px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to seperate them. For example you could use a bootstrap stylesheet in your `base.html` (read [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/13/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-forms-with-django.html)).

when installed you could do it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-1">
        {% for x in filter.weights %}  
            <div class="col-sm-XX">
                 {{x}}
            </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div> 
</div>
```

where XX should be a suitable size. Keep in mind bootstrap divedes the page in 12 parts. Also it comes with some css features.

Update for your edit:
assign a class to your checkbox and go for the class in the css. You can also use the built in `x.as_p` to display it as `<p>` element.